# How to get all tags from github api

Tags: api, github, curl, postman

I usually get the releases/tags from github API with below command

```
$ repo="helm/helm"
$ curl -sL https://api.github.com/repos/${repo}/tags |jq -r ".[].name"

v3.2.0-rc.1
v3.2.0
v3.1.3
v3.1.2
v3.1.1
v3.1.0-rc.3
v3.1.0-rc.2
v3.1.0-rc.1
v3.1.0
v3.0.3
v3.0.2
v3.0.1
v3.0.0-rc.4
v3.0.0-rc.3
v3.0.0-rc.2
v3.0.0-rc.1
v3.0.0-beta.5
v3.0.0-beta.4
v3.0.0-beta.3
v3.0.0-beta.2
v3.0.0-beta.1
v3.0.0-alpha.2
v3.0.0-alpha.1
v3.0.0
v2.16.6
v2.16.5
v2.16.4
v2.16.3
v2.16.2
v2.16.1
```

But in fact, it doesn't list all releases, what should I do?

For example, I can't get release before v2.16.1 as below link

https://github.com/helm/helm/tags?after=v2.16.1

I try to reference the same way to add `?after=v2.16.1` in curl api 
 command, but no help

```
curl -sL https://api.github.com/repos/${repo}/tags?after=v2.16.1 |jq -r ".[].name"
```

I got same output.

**Reference**:  https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29109673/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-latest-tag-of-a-given-repo-using-github-api-v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because of [pagination](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/)

[See this script](https://gist.github.com/mbohun/b161521b2440b9f08b59#file-githubapi-get-sh) as an example of detecting pages, and adding the required `?page=x` to access to all the data from a GitHub API call.

Relevant extract:

```
# single page result-s (no pagination), have no Link: section, the grep result is empty                                                                                                                                                                  
last_page=`curl -s -I "https://api.github.com${GITHUB_API_REST}" -H "${GITHUB_API_HEADER_ACCEPT}" -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" | grep '^Link:' | sed -e 's/^Link:.*page=//g' -e 's/>.*$//g'`

# does this result use pagination?                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
if [ -z "$last_page" ]; then
    # no - this result has only one page                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    rest_call "https://api.github.com${GITHUB_API_REST}"
else
    # yes - this result is on multiple pages                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    for p in `seq 1 $last_page`; do
        rest_call "https://api.github.com${GITHUB_API_REST}?page=$p"
    done
fi
```

Comment: thanks, your answer gives me the instruction to get the proper query string, it should be `?page=2`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

With help from @VonC, I got the result with extra query string `?page=2`, if I'd like to query older releases and so on.

```
curl -sL https://api.github.com/repos/${repo}/tags?page=2 |jq -r ".[].name"
```

I can easily get the last page now.

```
$ GITHUB_API_REST="/repos/helm/helm/tags"
$ GITHUB_API_HEADER_ACCEPT="Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json"
$ GITHUB_TOKEN=xxxxxxxx
$ last_page=`curl -s -I "https://api.github.com${GITHUB_API_REST}" -H "${GITHUB_API_HEADER_ACCEPT}" -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" | grep '^Link:' | sed -e 's/^Link:.*page=//g' -e 's/>.*$//g'`
$ echo $last_page
4
```